# How to move to the next line in binding.pry ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pry, binding.pry

In byebug we can move to next line by typing 'n', similarly is there anyway to move to the next line in 'pry' ?

I have gone through there documentation but nothing's works out.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check out [pry-nav](https://github.com/nixme/pry-nav), it gives you methods like `next` and `step`, which should be what you're looking for.

If you're in regular old Pry you can use `exit` to go to the next `binding.pry` or `disable-pry` to exit Pry entirely.

Comment: There's also [`pry-byebug`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) to combine these two libraries.

Comment: @user9015957 What do you mean, "it doesn't work"? You need to be a bit more specific about exactly what you have tried and what errors you are seeing. I suggest you create a new question with a more complete description of the problem, if you are still having difficulty.

Comment: It seems like `pry-nav` and `pry-rails` currently require different versions of `pry` and are incompatible.

Answer (score 22):

You can't. pry doesn't have any command who let you jump to the next line. So, your alternatives are:

1. Adding a new `pry.binding` on the next breakpoint and then using `exit` to jump between bingings.
2. Using a gem like `pry-byebug` or `pry-nav` who adds the `next` command to jump to the next line.
3. Using a gem like `pry-byebug` or `pry-debugger` who adds the `break` command to add breakpoints like `break <Class#method>`.

Installing `pry-byebug` is the best solution for your case, you can't achieve this with just `pry`.

Answer (score 5):

you can `exit` to continue the code flow

Comment: Why was this answer down voted? Please leave comments when down voting answers. This is the correct answer without using any additional libraries.

Comment: Because he is asking how to go to next line not how to exit the breaking point, just like 'next' || 'n' in byebug

Comment: He is asking how to go to the next line in binding.pry. When you use binding.pry, the flow of the execution stops on that line and to resume the flow you use exit. If you want to stop at the next line, you can place another binding.pry there but that would be kind of pointless

Comment: instead of placing multiple pry you can use   gem 'pry-byebug'
to take advantage of both gems

Comment: You are right but I was trying to answer him without any additional gems. Why would anyone place multiple binding.pry :p